# (Beginner) Extract number from input

Tags: python

Hi I am a beginner for python and have created this VERY BAD sample code just to show what I am trying to do.

I am trying to extract numbers from an input for example, lets say I use the letter "UK" for temperatures and have the user input them like this:

```
UK20
UK15
UK17
```

So `UK` is just the name for the location and then `20, 15, 17` are the temperatures listed.

How do I go about and **take away the "UK"** from the input so that I am **left with the numbers only** and be able to use them for calculations e.g. average etc.

Sorry if this made no sense but let me know if you need me to elaborate.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text, not an image, so we can copy and paste it.

Comment: You can do it using the `replace()` function.

Comment: If you know what kind of strings you want to remove - just ```replace``` them with nothing ```""```. Other thing is, whether you need some more parsing i.e. could it be e.g. ```UK57UK23``` and then produce 2 separate numbers out of it: ```[57, 23]```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **regular expression** to separate integers and chars from a string in python.
For eg:-

```
import re
data = 'abcdef12345'
re.split('(\d+)',data)
output ==> ['abcdef', '12345']
```

where `\d+` matches 1-or-more digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use re.sub to replace any non-digit characters in a string

```py
import re
str = 'UK20'
num_str = re.sub(r'[^\d]+','', str)
print(num_str)
>>> '20'
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer does not involve importing a heavy `re` module and it's much simpler:

```py
from string import ascii_letters as letters  # place this line at the beginning of your file
reading = int(reading.lstrip(letters))  # place this line after user's input
```

The above piece of code alters `'UK20'` into `20`.